Why pgAdmin run my job every 2 minutes when there is no job schedule end date?
I have a testing job that I create using pgAgent interface, and then I insert the schedule using this query:
INSERT INTO pgagent.pga_schedule (jscjobid, 
    jscname, 
    jscdesc,
    jscenabled)
VALUES (2,
    'Run Now', 
    'Runs immediately once', 
    true);

When I select the pgagent.pga_schedule to look for the schedule, it comes like this (no jscend or job schedule end date time)

9 3   "Run Now"   "Runs immediately once" true    "2024-05-20
14:12:56.654999+07"       "{f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f}" "{f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f}" "{f,f,f,f,f,f,f}"   "{f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f}" "{f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f}"

I need an explanation as to why is this job running every 2 minutes even though the jscminutes is all false but without jscend?
(I need to find out how to change this behavior, from every 2 minutes to every 10 seconds. Or a way to trigger or start a job from query, not from the interface)
